# Zeta function to Euler product

Tags: euler-product

I heard that the progress zeta function to Euler product is like below
$$\zeta(s) = 1+\frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{3^s}+\frac{1}{4^s}+...$$
$$\frac{1}{2^s}\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{4^s}+\frac{1}{6^s}+\frac{1}{8^s}+...$$
$$(1-\frac{1}{2^s})\zeta(s) = 1+\frac{1}{3^s}+\frac{1}{5^s}+\frac{1}{7^s}+...$$
$$\frac{1}{3^s}(1-\frac{1}{2^s})\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{3^s}+\frac{1}{9^s}+\frac{1}{15^s}+\frac{1}{21^s}+...$$
$$(1-\frac{1}{3^s})(1-\frac{1}{2^s})\zeta(s) = 1+\frac{1}{5^s}+\frac{1}{7^s}+\frac{1}{11^s}+...$$
and then repeat this process
$$...(1-\frac{1}{5^s})(1-\frac{1}{3^s})(1-\frac{1}{2^s})\zeta(s) = 1$$
$$\zeta(s) = \prod_{p = prime}(1-p^{-s})^{-1}$$
I got some questions, isn't it true that last formula is true where $s \in \mathbb{C}$? even if right side(Euler product) diverges, left side(zeta function) also diverges and I think the last formula is true for all complex number **s**.
And I'm wondering about what error is in my thought.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that $\zeta(s)$, in its traditional summation or Euler's product forms, only converges (and does so absolutely) for $s \in \Bbb C$ such that $\text{Re}(s) > 1$. Throughout this entire process, our manipulations are only justified as a result of that: that is, in transforming $\zeta$ from a sum to a product, you implicitly have to assume absolute convergence, and thus $\text{Re}(s)>1$.

Comment: In addition to this, the "repeat this process" in the OP involves infinitely many steps, and therefore would also require some kind of analytic justification.

Comment: You said zeta function is only defined for complex number s whose real part is greater than 1. but, doesn't it exist some complex number s whose real part is less than 1 and make zeta function converges?(like 0.5, -2, -4, -6, etc.)

Comment: Only if you analytically continue the zeta function, which gives you definitions for $\text{Re}(s) \le 1$ (except $s = 1$). However, these are not strictly in terms of the Euler product or the summation. You might want to look more into the functional equation of the zeta function.